# Spackling / Polyfilla on external wall?

Tags: spackling-paste

I've just realised the Polyfilla (aka spackling outside of the UK) I've used to fill an external wall plug I removed earlier, is not explicitly stated for external wall use.

Whilst the hole is small, should I consider removing it all before it dries, or am okay to leave 'as-is' for now?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

People make exterior walls out of mud, not just desert dwellers with their adobe construction, even people in England did it: Tudor architecture.  Ok Tudor walls aren't fully mud, but your patch isn't a full wall either.

Pollyfilla is probably better than mud, give it  several coats of paint and it will last for years.

Answer (score 0):

It probably won't last very long (like past the next rain storm), but it probably won't cause any lasting damage. If it's still wet, you could scrape out as much as you can before it hardens, then chip out the remainder after it's dried and use an appropriate filler for whatever material you're filling.

If you'd prefer, you could leave it until it rains again and see what happens. It is likely to soften and wash away, and when it does, you can finish the job or let the rain do it for you over time.

If you let it happen naturally, do be aware that you're leaving a hole open into the inner workings of your house and that rain is going to be getting inside, doing whatever damage it cares to do. Therefore, letting this go on too long is not recommended.